# Security Updates in R and/or RStudio

Tags: r, security, shiny, rstudio, updates

I made a shinyApp for pseudonymization of patient data which we want to use in our clinic. In order to prevent the app being hacked and to [ensure that the code will always run in the future](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71127911/reproducibility-failing-to-rerun-code-over-time) we want to use it locally, i.e. R would be blocked by the firewall and we would use the app offline.

Now a coworker responsible for security asks how R gets its security updates if it is offline. I have no idea what to say. The easiest answer is that in this constellation R obviously can not get any kind updates. But I wonder whether there security updates for R at all. **Do the regular R and/or RStudio updates include security fixes?**

Comment: a small blog related to this topic: https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360042593974-R-and-R-Package-Security

Comment: @Mike My colleague in charge of security did not like that at all. In exaggerated terms one can say that R can't be used in professional context because of the lack of any security methods there is always a risk. And the question is: Who is responsible for the risk? It's not R and I don't want to be the one either. We are handling clinical data which is really sensitive stuff. That is really a big point against R.

Comment: its an interesting point for sure and I am not a security expert by any means so I am out of my depth here. but if the app is offline and only stored locally how would anyone else access the data? is this assuming a nefarious package can still access data your data without your permission/

Comment: @Mike an idea: R itself will be offline but it will be installed on computers with access to the internet. I can imagine that this is already of some risk in case someone hacks the computer and goes to the R files (which are maybe vulnerable because R has no security measures).

Comment: You can use security scanners like [trivy](https://github.com/aquasecurity/trivy) or [ZAP](https://www.zaproxy.org/) (for shiny or web apps in general) to check R and its software dependencies for known vulnerabilities.